# Parse JSON Error: Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Am trying to parse this string using `JSON.parse`.

**Ex.**

```
str = "{'xyz': ['300543979001'], 'abc': ['1193'], 'serial_no': ['1'], 'product_tax_amt': ['408.813'], 'product_mrp': ['4699.0'], 'product_qty': ['1.0'], 'contract_type': ['FG'], 'product_tax_rate': ['14.5'], 'is_vat_exclusive': ['True'], 'product_net_amt': ['3228.213'], 'sap_details': [''], 'reference_invoice_no': [''], 'pd': [\"1||9911143976001||18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5||11143976||PUMA-18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5-5||4699.0||291||629||1||2||41\"], 'topup_offers': ['{}'], 'product_discount_percentage': ['40.0'], 'total_discount_percentage': ['40.0'], 'basic_tax_rate': ['0.0'], 'total_discount_amt': ['1879.6'], 'product_return_qty': ['0.0'], 'product_gross_amt': ['0.0'], 'invoice_no': ['11065011391'], 'product_discount_amt': ['1879.6'], 'is_voided': ['False'], 'supplier_no': ['198'], 'addl_tax_rate': ['0.0'], 'product_cost_amt': ['1.0'], 'code': ['4046643889059']}"
```

**Note:**: This is in single quoted & few values might contains quotes also, like `[\"1||9911143976001||18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5||11143976||PUMA-18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5-5||4699.0||291||629||1||2||41\"]`

```
>> JSON.parse(str)
```

But its throwing error: `Unexpected token '`

**EDITED**

I tried few here and there things to replace these single quotes with double quotes,

```
>> str = str.replace(/'/g, '"')
>> JSON.parse(str)
```

But then it raises error,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
```

Is there any way using `regex` or something, so i could parse that string?

Comment: You need double quotes (`"`) instead of single ones (`'`). Which of course means you will have to escape them in the string, like `\"`.

Comment: that data responded by server, now how to resolve this, so we could parse that?

Comment: I just added an answer, see if it works for you. But I still hope somebody has a better one.

Comment: I got parse error for very simple string: '{"title": "Title exists"}' ?! The firefox debugger interprets the string as json data correclty, but js does'nt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's the point: if that's data from the server, that's a terrible data format. It's not valid JSON and it has poor string escaping. In your case, you would want to change single quotes with doubles, as many already suggested, but you have horrible fields like this:

```
[\"1||9911143976001||18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5||11143976||PUMA-18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5-5||4699.0||291||629||1||2||41\"]
```

Now, the ideal solution would be to fix the `'`s with some kind of regular expression, but:

1) I couldn't for the life of me figure out a working one;

2) I'm starting to think it's not actually possible to catch every possibility.

I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong about this. Anyway, if this is actually the case, I think the easiest way is the most discouraged one: the dreadful `eval()`. That thing may not be valid JSON, but it is (surprisingly) a correct JS object definition.

```
eval("var data = " + str);
```

If you need a JSON string, you could use `stringify()`:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKuJP/2/).

I have to say this in advance: suggesting `eval()` is a terrible move on this website, and rightly so. But before downvoting please consider that we have a pathological data format from the server, and no easy way to fix it before processing. And I will say it again: if somebody can come up with a working regular expression for replacing an arbitrary number of single quotes within double quotes that will certainly be a far better way to go.

**EDIT:**

If you are sure that the only problematic field is the `pd` one, you could use that information to simply replace all single quotes in that particular field. That would be much safer.

Answer (score 3):

One of your fields has single quotes in it:

```
9911143976001||18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S, PINK, 5||11143976**strong text**
```

Try removing them, or escaping them.

Comment: Could you please help me to remove these thru regex?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is wrong, according to [json.org](http://www.json.org):

> An array is an ordered collection of **values**...

And

> A value can be a string in **double quotes**, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array.

So you must wrap your strings in double quotes instead of single quotes.

---

Edit:

A valid `JSON` would be:

```
{
  "xyz": [
    "300543979001"
  ],
  "abc": [
    "1193"
  ],
  "serial_no": [
    "1"
  ],
  "product_tax_amt": [
    "408.813"
  ],
  "product_mrp": [
    "4699.0"
  ],
  "product_qty": [
    "1.0"
  ],
  "contract_type": [
    "FG"
  ],
  "product_tax_rate": [
    "14.5"
  ],
  "is_vat_exclusive": [
    "True"
  ],
  "product_net_amt": [
    "3228.213"
  ],
  "sap_details": [
    ""
  ],
  "reference_invoice_no": [
    ""
  ],
  "pd": [
    "1||9911143976001||18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S",
    "PINK",
    "5||11143976||PUMA-18373205-L-I-F-T- RACER WN'S",
    "PINK",
    "5-5||4699.0||291||629||1||2||41"
  ],
  "topup_offers": [
    "{}"
  ],
  "product_discount_percentage": [
    "40.0"
  ],
  "total_discount_percentage": [
    "40.0"
  ],
  "basic_tax_rate": [
    "0.0"
  ],
  "total_discount_amt": [
    "1879.6"
  ],
  "product_return_qty": [
    "0.0"
  ],
  "product_gross_amt": [
    "0.0"
  ],
  "invoice_no": [
    "11065011391"
  ],
  "product_discount_amt": [
    "1879.6"
  ],
  "is_voided": [
    "False"
  ],
  "supplier_no": [
    "198"
  ],
  "addl_tax_rate": [
    "0.0"
  ],
  "product_cost_amt": [
    "1.0"
  ],
  "code": [
    "4046643889059"
  ]
}
```

And [here](http://jsbin.com/uheyeg/5) is a `JSBin Demo`.

PS: I'm not sure if there should be `"`s in first and last elements of `pd` array. If so just add `\"`s to these values.

Comment: Could you please do these for me?

Comment: I agreed with your example, but my string contains `'xyz'` not `"xyz"`, so in that case how to parse that?

Answer (score 1):

JSON strings are delimited with double quote `"` characters. You are using single quote characters, which is legal in JavaScript literals, but not in JSON.

It is useful to use a tool such as [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) (which would have picked up this error) to test your JSON when you craft it by hand. (Usually you should use a well-tested library function to generate your JSON).

Comment: Yes, am aware about that, but this data am getting from server end,
so now how to tackle that, please suggest me?

Answer (score -1):

Using single Quotes `(' ')` is badpractice-- U better use Double Quotes `(" ")` for `Literals`. 
For Example:

```
 var str = '{ "foo": "bar" }';
 var json = JSON.parse(str); 
 json['foo']
```

Comment: It isn't "badpractice", it's plain invalid.

Comment: While I agree with you, this doesn't answer his question. (He needs to make sure any quotes are escaped on encoding).